# How to sum the int values of a String variable?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to sum some values of a string I pull from a database and then store it in a variable again with it´s consecutive. Like this:

```
Dim x = PNR1
```

And then take the variable value, add 1 and then store it again to insert in a new sql row so it would end up like this:
x = PNR2... then PNR3 and so on

Hope someone can help me, thank you

Comment: Is this value stored in the database as a string? Are you trying to used this as a unique value for a primary Key? What database are you using? Is this a multi user environment?

Comment: Hello Mary, yes it is a string stored in sql server. I have to pull it, add 1 and store a new row (invoice) with a consecutive. I´m not trying to use it as a primary or foreign key, it is a multi user environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Substring` to get the interger portion of the string. Starts at the third index and goes to the end of the string. Convert to a number with `CInt`. Then increment the number and recombine to a string with and an interpolated string.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim input = "PRN1"
    Dim numericPortion = CInt(input.Substring(3))
    numericPortion += 1
    Dim newPRN = $"PRN{numericPortion}"
    Debug.Print(newPRN)
End Sub
```